# Sum a column using Recursive query in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query, recursive-cte

**Question**
I've got a Redshift table which contains hierarchal data by month. I am trying to calculate sum for manager based on people under them but struggling to get the SQL working. Actual data contains multiple levels.

**Example**
Sum of Bob's 'Person_actual' is some of all 'Person_actual' column for all the people reporting into him. Reading online I can see i've to use recursive query but can't get it working. Any guidance

**Sample Data**
| Person_owner_id | Person_id | Person_target | Person_actual | Date_description
|-----------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|-----------------
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Jan-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Feb-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Mar-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Apr-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |May-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Jun-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Jul-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Aug-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Sep-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Oct-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Nov-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Dec-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |9              |Jan-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |9              |Feb-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |7              |Mar-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |5              |Apr-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |6              |May-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |3              |Jun-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |2              |Jul-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Aug-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Sep-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Oct-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Nov-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Dec-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |9              |Jan-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |9              |Feb-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |7              |Mar-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |5              |Apr-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |6              |May-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |3              |Jun-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |2              |Jul-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Aug-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Sep-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Oct-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Nov-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Dec-23

**Expected Output**
| Person_owner_id | Person_id | Person_target | Person_actual | Date_description
|-----------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|-----------------
|                 |Bob        |               |18             |Jan-23
|                 |Bob        |               |19             |Feb-23
|                 |Bob        |               |8              |Mar-23
|                 |Bob        |               |10             |Apr-23
|                 |Bob        |               |12             |May-23
|                 |Bob        |               |6              |Jun-23
|                 |Bob        |               |4              |Jul-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Aug-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Sep-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Oct-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Nov-23
|                 |Bob        |               |               |Dec-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |9              |Jan-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |9              |Feb-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |7              |Mar-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |5              |Apr-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |6              |May-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |3              |Jun-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |2              |Jul-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Aug-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Sep-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Oct-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Nov-23
|Bob              |Chris      |10             |               |Dec-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |9              |Jan-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |10             |Feb-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |1              |Mar-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |5              |Apr-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |6              |May-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |3              |Jun-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |2              |Jul-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Aug-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Sep-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Oct-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Nov-23
|Bob              |Ali        |10             |               |Dec-23

Answer (score 0):

```sql
--- Table definition
CREATE TABLE rstable (
  Person_owner_id TEXT,
  Person_id TEXT,
  Person_target INTEGER,
  Person_actual INTEGER,
  Date_description TEXT
);

--- Recreating data as insert statement
INSERT INTO rstable (Person_owner_id, Person_id, Person_target, Person_actual, Date_description) VALUES
('Bob', NULL, 18, 0, 'Jan-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 19, 0, 'Feb-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 8, 0, 'Mar-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 10, 0, 'Apr-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 12, 0, 'May-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 6, 0, 'Jun-23'),
('Bob', NULL, 4, 0, 'Jul-23'),
('Bob', NULL, NULL, 0, 'Aug-23'),
('Bob', NULL, NULL, 0, 'Sep-23'),
('Bob', NULL, NULL, 0, 'Oct-23'),
('Bob', NULL, NULL, 0, 'Nov-23'),
('Bob', NULL, NULL, 0, 'Dec-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 9, 'Jan-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 9, 'Feb-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 7, 'Mar-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 5, 'Apr-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 6, 'May-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 3, 'Jun-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10, 2, 'Jul-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10,NULL,'Aug-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10,NULL,'Sep-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10,NULL,'Oct-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10,NULL,'Nov-23'),
('Bob', 'Chris', 10,NULL,'Dec-23'),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,9 ,'Jan-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,9 ,'Feb-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,7 ,'Mar-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,5 ,'Apr-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,6 ,'May-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,3 ,'Jun-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10 ,2 ,'Jul-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10,NULL,'Aug-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10,NULL,'Sep-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10,NULL,'Oct-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10,NULL,'Nov-23' ),
('Bob','Ali' ,10,NULL,'Dec-23');
```

The query

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t(
  Person_owner_id,
  Person_id,
  Person_target,
  Person_actual,
  Date_description,
  SUM_ACTUAL
) AS (
  SELECT
    Person_owner_id,
    Person_id,
    Person_target,
    Person_actual,
    Date_description,
    SUM(Person_actual) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Person_owner_id
      ORDER BY Date_description
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS SUM_ACTUAL
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        Person_owner_id,
        Person_id,
        Person_target,
        Person_actual,
        Date_description
      FROM
        rstable
    ) t
  WHERE
    Person_owner_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  t.Person_owner_id,
  t.Person_id,
  t.Person_target,
  t.Person_actual,
  t.Date_description,
  t.SUM_ACTUAL
FROM
  t;
```

We first create a recursive CTE called `t`. It starts with the rows where the `Person_owner_id` is `NULL`. These rows represent the top-level managers. The query then calculates the cumulative sum of the `Person_actual` column for each manager and their subordinates. The query continues to iterate through the `t` CTE until there are no more rows and here's the output
[image: Query result]

Comment: Hi @PGzlan, thanks for the answer. However, it is not what I am after. As it shows in your output, you are summing Ali based on Chris as well. 

In our output, Ali & Chris should remain as it is as they do not have any subordinates but Bob should have a sum based on Ali & Chris.

Example (for sum_actual):
Bob | Jan 23 | 18
Ali | Jan 23 | 9
Chris Jan 23 | 9
Bob | Feb 23 | 18
Ali | Feb 23 | 9
Chris | Feb 23 | 9

Logic: For each month, sum the actual value for all the subordinates just for that month

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results I wanted with following query:

```
SELECT
    t1.person_owner_id,
    t1.date_from,
    COALESCE(SUM(t2.person_actual), 0) AS sum_person_actual
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_owner_id, date_from
    FROM staging.rstable
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM staging.rstable
    WHERE person_id IS NOT NULL
) AS subordinates
LEFT JOIN staging.rstable AS t2
    ON t1.person_owner_id = t2.person_owner_id
    AND t1.date_from = t2.date_from
    AND t2.person_id = subordinates.person_id
GROUP BY t1.person_owner_id, t1.date_from
ORDER BY t1.person_owner_id, t1.date_from;
```